# How does PageRank work on individual social media pages?

Tags: pagerank

I'm using SEOprofiler to check the backlinks to individual pages. When I look at, for example, twitter.com/microsoft, it has very few backlinks (I was able to find just one). However, it shows up at second place on Google for the keyword "microsoft", second only to the official Microsoft homepage. How/why does Google give the Microsoft's twitter page such a high ranking without it having many backlinks?

Comment: There are lots of factors used to rank pages. Links are just one of them and quantity is not nearly as important as you think. Like, it's not important at all.